# sorting numbers when their digits are separated

Tags: c#, sorting, gridview, types, digits

There is a column in my datagrid which shows some numbers. Since these numbers are too large, I need to seperate their digits for the sake of reading them easier.(1985318 -> 1,985,318) I do this by using this code:

```
int value = (int) Convert.ToInt64(GridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
string seperated = value.ToString("N1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
GridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = seperated.Remove(seperated.Length - 2);
```

Obviously I had to assign the datatype of these numbers to `"LongText"` in `MS Access` (Because "1,985,318" is not a number). But the problem is that since they are defined as strings and not numbers, when I try to sort them they do not become sorted properly.
I thought I cannot simultaneously have their digits separated and sort them properly.

Do you have any suggestions on how can it be done?

Comment: You should set the display format instead of formatting yourself. That way, the underlying values will remain numbers and they will sort correctly. See [Set Display format for winform DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340292/set-display-format-for-winform-datagridview).

Comment: @RobertBaron Thanks for your response. I managed to solve the problem with string formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as RobertBaron mentioned, I solved the problem using String formatting. I used the following code in Grid_CellFormatting EventHandler:

```
private void Grid_CellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
        GridViewDecimalColumn myCol = Grid.Columns[2] as GridViewDecimalColumn;
        myCol.FormatString = "{0:###,###,###,###,###,###,###}";
}
```